# Creating Code-Behind file - aspx.cs

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2010

I am using VS2010 and I created a ASP.net empty web application, but I cannot for the life of me get it to generate an index.aspx.cs file. I double click any control in the view and I just get nothing. What could I possibly be missing? I used to be able to just double click on a control and it would automatically generate the .cs if it didn't exist.

Comment: Is it possible you accidentally created an empty ASP.NET MVC project?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you add a new item to the project and pick "web form" as type, you should have both `index.aspx` and the code behind file. Double-clicking controls does not generate the code behind file, it only adds event handlers to it. Take a look at [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k4cbh4dh.aspx) walkthrough.

Comment: That would explain it. I was importing aspx files from another project and they weren't dropping in with .cs files. It is however possible to create them manually right?

Comment: Of course, just create an empty file with the correct name (same as the `.aspx`, but with `.cs`) and make sure it matches the `CodeBehind` attribute of the `@Page` tag in the `aspx` (switch to markup view and scroll all the way to the top to see it). Also, the class name in the `.cs` file should match whatever the `Inherits` attribute of the `@Page` tag says.

Answer (score 1):

In your project file (csproj), make sure that you have the `DependentUpon` tag which indicates that the `aspx.cs` file depends on the `aspx` file.  Here is an example:

```
<Compile Include="dir\myFile.aspx.cs">
      <DependentUpon>myFile.aspx</DependentUpon>
      <SubType>ASPXCodeBehind</SubType>
</Compile>
```

This worked for me.

Comment: Which means i have to create a myFile.aspx.cs inside the view ? And where should i have the above code ?